# Access Client IP within Elastic Beanstalk/Docker Nginx/PHP-FPM instance

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In an attempt to make things easier for deployment and developers after me, I have deployed our REST API on an Elastic Beanstalk instance, using their Docker Container service.

All works great except getting the Client IP of those connecting to the API and all attempts I've tried so far, have resulted in either the same Docker Container IP being returned, or an HTTP 499 error message.

**Nginx Configuration**

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name api.zecofrontend.local
    index index.php index.html;

    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**Docker Compose**

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www
            - ./vhost.local.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
        links:
            - app
        depends_on:
            - app
    app:
        image: php7.1-fpm-base
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www
```

Running the above configuration, returns me a 172.18.0.1 IP Address, that of the docker container/host it self.

I have a different configuration for local and Elastic Beanstalk deployed instances, however the only difference is related to SSL Certificates.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are missing two directives in your nginx http section `real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;` and `set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;`, basically you need to tell nginx how to get that real ip. I have used `0.0.0.0/0` but once can use the IP of the LB which is sending the request

Answer (score 0):

AWS ELB automatically adds some headers to each request. Check out the docs on  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for

In your case what you need is to use X-Forwarded-For which contains the IP of a client that is accessing the website through your ELB.